# how can i display the search result of employee's records in my txt file through PHP?

Tags: php, html, file-handling

i was ask to make an php file that would search an employees id no. and displays its results on the same page from a txt file for its records...like this....

---

expected output (results on the same page):

Search employee record

employee id no.: ***12347*** search

Result:
Lastname : Smith
Firstname : Sam
Position : Encoder

note: 
if the user input is not found
expected message will be
"the id number you entered is not valid."

example sourced file: emp_record.txt

12345,Villaceran,Emelie,Instructor,20000
12346,Ayala,Jelyn,Encoder,8000
12347,Smith,Samuel,Encoder,8000

---

but i have been struggling putting an error note if the user input is not found... also not sure if my code structure is fit for this.... i am thinking if i should use functions for searching record and also reading and saving employees array. how can i saved the employees data into an array? i dont know if where can i insert it.....
can someone help me with this...

this is my php code..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search Employee</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Search Employee Record</h1>
        <form method = "POST">`enter code here`
        <h3>Employee ID No. :
        <input type = "text" name = "id_no" >
        <input type = "submit" value = "Search"></h3>
        <?php
            if($_POST){
                $idnumber = ($_POST["id_no"]);
                $empfile = fopen("emp_record.txt", "r") or die ("Unable to open file");
                while (!feof($empfile)){
                    $employee = fgets($empfile);
                    $emp_record = explode(",", $employee);
                    $emp_id = $emp_record[0];
                    $emp_lastname = $emp_record[1];
                    $emp_firstname = $emp_record[2];
                    $emp_position = $emp_record[3];
                    $emp_salary = $emp_record[4];

                    if ($emp_id == $idnumber){
                        echo "Lastname : $emp_lastname <br> Firstname : $emp_lastname <br> Position : $emp_position <br>";
                    }else{
                        echo "The ID number you entered is NOT VALID.";
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

also this is my code using functions... I know there is still missing in my code. i dont know if how can i save the record datas in an array...

---

```
    <?php
$empfile = fopen("emp_record.txt", "r") or die ("Unable to open file");
function record(){
    while (!feof($empfile)){
        $employee = fgets($empfile);
        $emp_record = explode(",", $employee);
        $emp_id = $emp_record[0];
        $emp_lastname = $emp_record[1];
        $emp_firstname = $emp_record[2];
        $emp_position = $emp_record[3];
        $emp_salary = $emp_record[4];
    }
    //an example loop to see if what is the datas in the variables
    // it only display the last line of data
    for($i=0;$i<count($emp_record);$i++){
        echo "$emp_id $emp_lastname $emp_firstname $emp_position ";
    }
}
?>
```

thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason as to why you're to use a text file as opposed to a database? Text files are a lot of work.

Comment: First of all, that's a CSV file. Secondly devise *a function* to read it and *return* a usable array from there. (Don't do any processing in that function / also variable scope issues). Make it associate ID→Values right away, and your problems solve itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you have displayed the persons details and if not, then display your message after the loop has finished (so you have checked all of the records).

You can also use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead of `fgets()` which will stop you having to do the `explode()` as well...

```
    $found = false;
    while ($emp_record = fgetcsv($empfile)){
        $emp_id = $emp_record[0];
        $emp_lastname = $emp_record[1];
        $emp_firstname = $emp_record[2];
        $emp_position = $emp_record[3];
        $emp_salary = $emp_record[4];

        if ($emp_id == $idnumber){
            echo "Lastname : $emp_lastname <br> Firstname : $emp_lastname <br> Position : $emp_position <br>";
            $found = true;
            break;  // Stop looking
        }
    }

    if ( $found == false ) {
        echo "The ID number you entered is NOT VALID.";
    }
```